# Does apache superset can be connected to prometheus directly?

Tags: prometheus, visualization, apache-superset

I want to display the data stored in prometheus using superset , does superset supports prometheus ?do we have solution for that?

I've tried to connect to prometheus database , but couldn't do it. So tried using influxDB to act as bridge between prometheus and superset , can we connect prometheus and superset directly?

Answer (score 0):

No, [Superset does not support Prometheus](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/18381) as a direct data source.

However, it is possible to connect Superset with Prometheus using Trino, like [mentioned here](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/18381#discussioncomment-2097480).

- [How to connect Trino and Prometheus](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/prometheus.html)
- [How to use Trino and Superset](https://trino.io/episodes/12.html)